# How can I extract rows in Dataframe with function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe includes list, like this.

```
       a        b
1     frog   [1, 2, 3]
2      dog   [4, 5]
3    melon   [6, 7, 1]
```

I want to extract rows which b contains specific numbers, so I made this function.

```
def a(_list, _tag):
    if _tag in _list:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I tried to use df.loc[], but it doesn't work well.
How can I write a code without iterating all of dataframe?

My expected output is this. If I want to find a row that contains '1' in b, output will be

```
      a      b
1    frog   [1, 2, 3]
3   melon   [6, 7, 1]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your expected output? Are you just checking on whether the value of `tag` is in each cell of column b?

Comment: `.explode('b')` and then run a `.loc()` query.

Comment: @VladimirVilimaitis OP said they didn't get the expected results with a `loc`. Perhaps you could explain? For example, `pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 2]}).explode('a').loc[2]` does not return a dataframe.

Comment: @philosofool Effectively, OP wants to search in a column composed of lists. `df.explode('b')` returns a dataframe where each value in a list is its own separate item. Afterwards, `df['b'].loc[df['b'].isin(target_hash_set)]` should work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
target = 1
df2 = df.explode('b').b == target
df['found'] = df2.groupby(df2.index).sum() > 0
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       a          b  found
0   frog  [1, 2, 3]   True
1    dog     [4, 5]  False
2  melon  [6, 7, 1]   True
```

Comment: To actually extract the rows, you would probably skip the addition of `found` and just mask the original dataframe: `df[df2.groupby(df2.index).sum() > 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.explode` in conjunction with `.loc` to get relevant unique indeces, and then query them with `.iloc`:

```
df.iloc[df.explode("b").loc[df["b"].isin(target_hash_set)].index.unique()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` function can be simplified as

```py
def a(_list, _tag):
    return _tag in _list
```

You can use it in `Series.apply`

```py
out = df['b'].apply(lambda _list: a(_list, _tag))
# or
out = df['b'].apply(lambda _list: _tag in _list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple `pandas` oneliner:

```
df[df.explode('B').eq(1).groupby(df.explode('B').A, sort=False).sum().B.apply(bool).values]
```

Output:

```
       A          B
0   frog  [1, 2, 3]
2  melon  [6, 7, 1]
```